# X-Frame-Options: Post on Twitter from Facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, x-frame-options

I want to be able to post on users Twitter feed from a Facebook app i'm developing at the moment but seem to be having trouble. When I call my the tmhOAuth PHP script to authenticate ask for permissions on Twitter I get the following error:

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options
```

TmhOAuth works perfectly when its called directly from the browser. Its the header function that fails inside the Facebook iframe.

Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter doesn't allow their OAuth authorization page to be contained within a frame, for phishing reasons. You need to open the OAuth flow in a new window, outside of Facebook's canvas.

Comment: u know whats wierd, facebook allows it, no?

Comment: @Ayyash I don't believe they do.

Comment: yup they dont.. gooe thing i saw this post, if ur already authenticated they let it pass, but if not, they dont